# Can I deploy the same modified CSS file to firebase hosting more than once?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

The solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905431/can-i-modify-my-html-css-files-easily-after-deploying-them-with-firebase) did not work for me. And [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252696/firebase-not-rendering-css-changes) suggests that firebase deploy does not overwrite the same CSS file. I'm able to deploy a new CSS file with a new name. But I'd like to keep the same CSS file, make changes, and deploy it again. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files that have changes will be deployed. The changes are detected by the `checksum`.
The name doesn't matter. As James More wrote on his comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601583/5519300):

> now is "will only deploy files with different checksums".

Do you experience a behaviour other than that? One thing you should consider is the CSS Cache in Browsers. It can get very tricky. Even when you update the CSS the Page shows the old one.

Comment: Clearing the cache worked. But how can I help users clear their caches?

Comment: It will happen automaicaly in the future. Maybe this can help you a little bit with that problem: https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Comment: Great idea. I may try using version numbers.